# Media Object con Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Es la primera vez que hago una pregunta. Disculpad si falta algún dato, aclaración o no me expreso bien.

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Bootstrap en su última versión (v5.0.0-beta3) y, siguiendo unos tutoriales, intento crear una caja de comentarios tipo red social, que salen los comentarios anidados. No entiendo por qué en mi código me aparece todo lineal, no se anida.

He buscado en la documentación de Bootstrap, he probado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido (dentro de lo poco que sé) y no he conseguido arreglarlo. He probado en dos navegadores distintos y tampoco se anida. Seguramente sea una tontería pero no me deja avanzar porque me deja intranquilo.

Muchas gracias.

```css
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.comments {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.form_comments textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 84px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 84px;
  max-height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #4b65d1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form_comments .btn {
  background-color: #4b65d1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form_comments .btn:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.media {
  border-top: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.media img {
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 999px;
}

.media .name {
  color: #4b65d1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.media .name span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #464646;
  margin: 20px;
}

.media .comments {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.media .buttons {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.media .buttons a {
  color: #acacac;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es-ES">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Comentarios</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row comments justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                <form class="form_comments d-flex justify-content-end flex-wrap">
                    <textarea placeholder="Comentario"></textarea>
                    <button class="btn" type="button">Comentar</button>
                </form>

                <div class="media">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64" alt="Karina" class="d-flex align-self-center">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <p class="name">Karina ST <span>11:56, hoy</span></p>
                        <p class="comment">
                            Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis eos dolore optio!

                        </p>
                        <div class="buttons text-end">
                            <a href="#">Responder</a>
                            <a href="#">Editar</a>
                            <a href="#">Eliminar</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="media">
                            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/64/64" alt="Karina" class="d-flex align-self-center">
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <p class="name">Karina <span>22:56, hoy</span></p>
                                <p class="comment">
                                    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis eos dolore optio!

                                </p>
                                <div class="buttons text-end">
                                    <a href="#">Responder</a>
                                    <a href="#">Editar</a>
                                    <a href="#">Eliminar</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <!--
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]. Podés convertir tu código a [snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet) para mostrar en la propia pregunta el problema que estás teniendo, con el botón que indica `<>`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no lo sabía!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap 5 [removió *media object*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#grid-and-layout). Como sugiere la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#media-object), podés replicar su comportamiento con las utilidades `flex`:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.comments {
  margin: 20px 0px;
}

.form_comments textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 84px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 84px;
  max-height: 250px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #4b65d1;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form_comments .btn {
  background-color: #4b65d1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form_comments .btn:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.media {
  border-top: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.media img {
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 999px;
}

.media .name {
  color: #4b65d1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.media .name span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #464646;
  margin: 20px;
}

.media .comments {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.media .buttons {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.media .buttons a {
  color: #acacac;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="es-ES">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Comentarios</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row comments justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-8">
        <form class="form_comments d-flex justify-content-end flex-wrap">
          <textarea placeholder="Comentario"></textarea>
          <button class="btn" type="button">Comentar</button>
        </form>
        <!--conservé "media" ya que aparece en los estilos; flex-direction-column para tomar la dirección de arriba para abajo (no de izquierda a derecha)-->
        <div class="media d-flex flex-direction-column">
          <div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64" alt="Karina" class="align-self-center">
          </div>
          <!--flex-grow se utiliza para que un elemento flex crezca hasta rellenar el espacio disponible
          ms (margin start) reemplaza a ml (margin left): https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/#approach-->
          <div class="flex-grow-1 ms-0">
            <p class="name">Karina ST <span>11:56, hoy</span></p>
            <p class="comment">
              Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis eos dolore optio!

            </p>
            <!--flex-direction-row para tomar la dirección de izquierda a derecha; justify-content-end para alinear los componentes a la derecha-->
            <div class="buttons text-end d-flex flex-direction-row justify-content-end">
              <a href="#">Responder</a>
              <a href="#">Editar</a>
              <a href="#">Eliminar</a>
            </div>

            <div class="media d-flex flex-direction-column">
              <!--flex-shrink por su parte se utiliza para que un elemento flex se encoja, de ser necesario. Si su valor es cero, no se encogerá cuando la página se haga más pequeña -->
              <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64" alt="Karina" class="d-flex align-self-center">
              </div>
              <div class="flex-grow-1 ms-0">
                <p class="name">Karina <span>22:56, hoy</span></p>
                <p class="comment">
                  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis eos dolore optio!
                </p>
                <div class="buttons text-end d-flex flex-direction-row justify-content-end">
                  <a href="#">Responder</a>
                  <a href="#">Editar</a>
                  <a href="#">Eliminar</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Agregué comentarios en el html para que se comprendan los cambios.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Supuse que esa característica habría quedado obsoleta pero no sabía cómo avanzar. Gracias de nuevo.